# Minimum number of entries to aggregate MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Currently, we have a collection storing the points of each user in categories and we perform an average aggregate on it.
The issue is that when we wish to query the leaderboards, the average is biased because if a user has points in only one category, he could be ranked first in the leaderboard just because categories where he hasn't got points are not counted in the average.

The collection goes like `{ userId: UUID, category: String, points: int }`.

```java
final AggregateIterable<Document> aggregate = mongo.getCollection("scores").aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        Aggregates.match(filter),
        Aggregates.group("$userId", Accumulators.avg("averagePoints", "$points")),
        Aggregates.sort(Sorts.descending("averagePoints")),
        Aggregates.limit(limit)
));
```

We've already thought about two possible solutions:

- Query users' points in each category and bake the average manually by inserting to the list until it matches our total count of categories. But this option turns out to be simply not applicable because we'd lose sorting.
- Insert default documents for all categories for each user. <del>The issue here being that we can add new categories without the application being running, meaning we can't run triggers on new category insertion.</del>

So, considering all of this, we're thinking there might be a way to set a minimum number of entries to aggregate on and a default value to fill non-present entries. But we haven't found anything on it, thus it may not exist after all, or it's well hidden.
How could we approach this problem?

**EDIT**: We ended up storing the last loaded categories in the database, so we can check the ones that changed on startup, and went with considered solution 2. This choice was actually the only reasonable one because we need to remove categories no longer existing from scores anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities come to mind here:

- in addition to calculating the average in the group stage, also count the number of value.  After the group stage, you can match eliminate those with too few entries, or include the number of entries in the sort.
- instead of calculating the average in the group stage, calculate the sum of all entries.  A user with that has points in multiple categories will be more likely to have a greater total than one with fewer categories.
- instead of average, calculate the sum and count of entries.  After the group stage you can conditionally replace the count with a minimum value, and then calculate the average with the new count.